# how to mock outbound gateways in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am currently learning spring integration framework. So please forgive and correct me if my question is absurd.
how to or is there a way to mock an http outbound gateway to run my unit tastcase?

```
public IntegrationFlow sendSms() {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        final JsonObjectMapper<?, ?> mapper = new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sendSmsGatewayRequestChannel")
                .handle(Http
                        .outboundGateway(environment.getProperty("integration.sms.endpoint")
                                + "?ProductType={ProductType}&MobleNo={MobleNo}&smsType={smsType}&Message={Message}")
                        .expectedResponseType(String.class).httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                        .uriVariableExpressions(createExpressionMap()))
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(SmsResponseDto.class, mapper)).get();
    }
```

this is my integration flow.

Also, can we use mockmvc for testing inbound gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a bean id to the handler as,

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sendSms() {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        final JsonObjectMapper<?, ?> mapper = new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sendSmsGatewayRequestChannel")
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway(smsEndpoint).expectedResponseType(String.class).httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                        .uriVariableExpressions(createExpressionMap()), **e -> e.id("smsOutboundGateway")**)
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(SmsResponseDto.class, mapper)).get();
    }
```

then you can mock the response by,

```
final ArgumentCaptor<Message<?>> messageArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Message.class);
        final MessageHandler mockMessageHandler = MockIntegration.mockMessageHandler(messageArgumentCaptor)
                .handleNextAndReply(m -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(
                        "response")
                        .build());
        mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor("smsOutboundGateway", mockMessageHandler);
```

Note: I am new to spring integration. so i don't know whether this is the correct way to do it. anyways, it's working :D. correct if i'm wrong. :)

Thanks Artem Bilan for the help.

Comment: Your code and logic is fully correct. Since `Http.outboundGateway()` is based on the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` which is essentially a `MessageHandler` implementation, it is really OK to use `substituteMessageHandlerFor` to mock that HTTP requests. The same can be done in any integration point of your flow.

Comment: i have created an actual bean of HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler . is there any way to mock its response like the above method? i am not able to use mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor. what is expected for the substitition is IntegrationConsumer bean. instead of HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler  bean. is there any way to mock it?

Comment: See my answer then: the Mock MVC is for you over there. Although you still can use substitute if you call it via sending messages to the channel of the endpoint you want to mock.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any `handle()` (or better to say `MessageHandler`) in the application can be mocked. For this purpose we need an `@SpringIntegrationTest` and `MockIntegration` API.

See more info in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing

And yes, with HTTP we really can use Mock MVC framework and its `MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory` to be injected into the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` represented by that `Http.outboundGateway()`.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-client

Comment: Hi Bilan, I need to unit test the flow. Not integration test. So i don't want to set up mock servers for that. is there any way to get the response after mocking for testing the entire flow?

Comment: in the integration flow i created i've added atransformer as well. so is there any alternative way for "mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor" method?

Comment: It is called an "integration" test, when you deal interaction between fully-blown services, in most cased over there network. It is really a goal of mock MVC to let us to avoid such a burden and have a plain unit test instead.

Comment: The `substituteMessageHandlerFor` work for transformer as well. Even if it is a gateway, or splitter, or an aggregator, still there is some `MessageHandler` which we can substitute with a mocked one.